# Mask Input Currency fields with comma separated format for Angular and Material UI

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, material-ui, angular-reactive-forms

For our Angular 9 application we have currency input fields that need to show a standard masked label with comma separated format.

So when the user inputs 56000.55 in the input field then on blur event we should display 56,000.55 as comma separated masked label without changing the original value of the control.
We are using Angular Reactive Forms with Mat Form Fields for this UI change.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the **number pipe**:

HTML

```
{{ 56000.55 | number }}
//56,000.55
```

Comment: So I need to be applied to my input form-field here, not on other read-only element.